# How to return Document that was used to answer a question using i am using RetrievalQA?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, artificial-intelligence, langchain

I am using python and langchain RetrievalQA for RAG. Here is sample of code that i have written:

```
loader = UnstructuredPDFLoader(filename, mode="elements")
data = loader.load()
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size = 300, chunk_overlap = 0)
splits = text_splitter.split_documents(data)
splits = chromautils.filter_complex_metadata(splits)
vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(documents=splits, embedding=embedding_function, persist_directory=PERSIST_DIRECTORY)
llm = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0, openai_api_key=OPENAI_KEY)
qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
        llm,
        retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(),
        chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": prompt},
        return_source_documents=True
    )
result = qa_chain({"query": question})
```

It only returns the answer to question. How to return Document from `splits` that was used as context to answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

[from docs](https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/question_answering/sources)

> ### Returning sources
>
> Often in Q&A applications it’s important to show users the sources
> that were used to generate the answer. The simplest way to do this is
> for the chain to return the Documents that were retrieved in each
> generation.

```
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnableParallel

rag_chain_from_docs = (
    RunnablePassthrough.assign(context=(lambda x: format_docs(x["context"])))
    | prompt
    | llm
    | StrOutputParser()
)

rag_chain_with_source = RunnableParallel(
    {"context": retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
).assign(answer=rag_chain_from_docs)

rag_chain_with_source.invoke("What is Task Decomposition")
```